# Devise 3.5.x on Rails 4.2.x timeout prints "true" underneath timeout flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

We have the "timeoutable" option set on Devise 3.5.x on our Rails 4.2 project. When a user times out due to inactivity, they are redirected to the sign in page and following flash message is printed:

```
Your session expired. Please sign in again to continue.
true
```

The undesired "true" beneath the "Your session expired..." flash message appears to be the result of our flash partial:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <% if !value.to_s.empty? %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, value, :class => "flash #{key}") %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It has come to our attention that this might not be the optimal way to iterate through flash messages. Whenever we manually set flash messages, we always use flash[:notice] or flash.now[:notice] (on render). Is there a better way to iterate through flash messages in our partial that will eliminate this supplemental "true" output on Devise timeout? If so, as we're not certain what "types" of flash messages various gems like Devise may be utilizing, what are all the flash types ([:notice], [:error], [:warning]) should we check for and iterate through?

Otherwise, since all other flash messages site-wide are working properly, is there any known way to simply prevent Devise from printing this supplemental "true" on timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a late reply, but this is what I did.

```
flash.each do |msg_type, message|
  unless msg_type.to_s == 'timedout'
  <!-- Carry on printing messages -->
```